# Perfect aspect ratio for responsive banner

Tags: react-native, responsive-design, tailwind-css

I am currently trying to clone crunchyroll app and i am stuck on responsive banner i notice that different size device render banner text in different location may be they use aspect ratio what are appropriate aspect ratio for HomeBannerInfo component.

Original App:
[image: Original App:]

Expo App:
[image: My Expo App]

```js
const HomeScreen = () => {
  return (
    <HomeBackground>
      <ScrollView className="flex-1 pl-4">
        <HomeBannerInfo />
      </ScrollView>
    </HomeBackground>
  );
};

const HomeBackground = ({ children }: { children?: ReactNode }) => {
  return (
    <ImageBackground
      source={require("@/mock-data/banner/2.jpg")}
      className="flex-1 bg-primary"
      resizeMode="cover"
    >
      {children}
    </ImageBackground>
  );
};

const HomeBannerInfo = () => {
  const Touchable: any =
    Platform.OS === "android" ? TouchableNativeFeedback : TouchableOpacity;

  return (
    <View className="justify-end gap-y-1.5">
      <Text className="text-[22px] font-semibold uppercase text-white">
        Frieren: Beyond Journey's End
      </Text>
      <Text className="text-xs capitalize text-gray-300">Dub | Sub</Text>
      <Text numberOfLines={3} className="tex-sm text-white">
        ....Desc
      </Text>
      <Touchable onPress={() => {}}>
        <View className="bg-crunchyrollOrange mt-4 w-40 flex-row items-center justify-center gap-x-1 py-2">
          <Feather name="play" size={25} color="black" />
          <Text className="text-base font-semibold uppercase">Watch Now</Text>
        </View>
      </Touchable>
    </View>
  );
};
```